# ObjectAnimator not working below API 24

Tags: android, animation

I'm having a issue with the `ObjectAnimator` that it's working in Nougat (API 24) perfectly but not working in Marshmallow or Lollipop.

Here's the code:

```
        ObjectAnimator animatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(settings,"x",1100, 950);
        ObjectAnimator rotateAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(settings,"rotation",360f,0f);
        animatorX.setDuration(1100);
        rotateAnimation.setDuration(1100);
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.playTogether(animatorX,rotateAnimation);
        animatorSet.start();
```

Any workaround will also be appreciated.

Comment: define `"not working"`

Comment: @pskink Nothing is happening, and the icon stays out of the screen.

Comment: are animation enabled in "developers options"?

Comment: tried with simple `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(settings,"x",0, 1000).setDuration(1000).start();` ?

Comment: i checked `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(settings,"x",0, 1000).setDuration(1000).start();` on 4.4 kitkat and it works like a charm, no problems at all

Comment: tried on 5.0 as well, and yes its working too, i could check on 6.0 but honestly i cant see any reason why it wouldnt work....

Comment: take [those](https://pastebin.com/raw/Y3VCpCDF) 8 lines of code, paste them to your `Activity#onCreate` method (do not change anything - just copy / paste) and run it

Comment: @pskink I got it finally, the values 1100 and 950 are too big for the devices I've (both are HD) which means my Icon stays out of screen with these values but in my other device (which is FHD) these values work great. Is there nothing like percentage for screen size ratios or something which can work in every screen resolution? and atlast those lines were in the onCreate().

Comment: so why you said `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(settings,"x",0, 1000).setDuration(1000).start();` did not work? you did not try it at all?

Comment: @pskink I did try it when you said it, but as I said it appeared for a split second and disappeared as 1000 is way far right than the most right part of the screen and I got the highest value my HD devices are supporting which is 550 (after decreasing the value in every try), after that view is out of the screen.